# MySQL Replace Numbers With Letters if a Certain Length

Tags: mysql

I need to write a SELECT statement that returns:

If the card number contains 16 digits, it should be displayed in this format: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1234, where 1234 are the actual last four digits of the number.

If the card number contains 15 digits, it should be displayed in this format: XXXX-XXXXXX-X1234.

I am stuck! Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I am trying to use If then Replace Or Case When

Comment: What's your MySQL version?

Comment: If you're in the US and storing credit card numbers, I hope all your processes are PCI compliant. You would probably be better off delegating this to a third-party credit card processing service.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL version that supports window function, I suggest using `REGEXP_REPLACE()` with `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()`. Here's an example:

```
SELECT cardnumber, CASE LENGTH(cardnumber)
       WHEN 19 THEN 
           CONCAT(LEFT(REGEXP_REPLACE(cardnumber,'[0-9]','X'),15), 
                      RIGHT(cardnumber,4)) 
       WHEN 17 THEN 
           CONCAT(LEFT(REGEXP_REPLACE(cardnumber,'[0-9]','X'),13), 
                      RIGHT(cardnumber,4)) 
       END AS masked_cardnum
FROM testtable;
```

On this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (
cardnumber VARCHAR(255));

INSERT INTO testtable VALUES
('1234-5678-9999-1234'),
('1234-567899-91234');
```

the query above will return the following result:

| cardnumber | masked_cardnum |
| --- | --- |
| 1234-5678-9999-1234 | XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-1234 |
| 1234-567899-91234 | XXXX-XXXXXX-X1234 |

Or probably, don't even need to replace the first 12 or 11 digits. Just directly append the last 4 digits with `XXX..`. This should work on any MySQL version:

```
SELECT cardnumber,
       CASE LENGTH(cardnumber)
          WHEN 19 THEN CONCAT('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-', RIGHT(cardnumber,4))
          WHEN 17 THEN CONCAT('XXXX-XXXXXX-X', RIGHT(cardnumber,4))
       END AS masked_cardnum
FROM testtable;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fe9b0d1762b14d4f4f4dd4d6bbcef27f)

Comment: This looks right. Now I see that I misunderstood the question. It's about masking digits, not about adding hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT()`, `SUBSTR()`, `RIGHT()` to extract the parts of the string, and `CONCAT_WS()` to concatenate them together with a `-` delimiter.

```
SELECT CASE LENGTH(cardnumber)
    WHEN 16 THEN CONCAT_WS('-', LEFT(cardnumber, 4), SUBSTR(cardnumber, 5, 4), SUBSTR(cardnumber, 9, 4), RIGHT(cardnumber, 4))
    WHEN 15 THEN CONCAT_WS('-', LEFT(cardnumber, 4), SUBSTR(cardnumber, 5, 6), RIGHT(cardnumber, 5)
END AS formatted_cardnumber
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Won't the `LENGTH(cardnumber)` include those dashes too? OP said 16 digit but it's actually 19 characters including dashes, right? And the other one is 17.

Comment: As I understand it, the length doesn't include the dashes. They're being added to create the formats desired.

Comment: Ahh, I get it.. I probably should consider the possibility of that as well.